# UnsupportedClassVersionError in sencha-app-refresh & sencha-app-build

Tags: java, extjs, ant, sencha-command

I am getting the above exception while run the 'ant dist' command at command prompt. I have installed ruby & sencha command. I am using java "1.5.0.06" and jre 6 in my system.

```
sencha-app-refresh:
[attrib] Applied attrib to 432 files and 0 directories.
[attrib] Applied attrib to 18 files and 0 directories.
[exec] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
[exec]  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
[exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
[exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
[exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
[exec]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[exec]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
[exec] Exception in thread "main" 
sencha-app-build:
[exec] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
[exec]  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
[exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
[exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
[exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
[exec]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[exec]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[exec]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
[exec]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
[exec] Exception in thread "main"
```

I am getting same exception while running 'sencha.exe' from command prompt.

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean that you use Java 1.5 and JRE 6? Those are two different versions. Sencha requires Java 6, so check if you are running it on Java 1.6.x, also the new version requires Java 7, see http://cdn.sencha.com/cmd/beta/4.0.0.126/release-notes.html

Comment: Thanks Martin. I am using Java 6 only.